# Bottom property on a relative child with a fixed parent doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a child element that have `position:relative ; bottom: 0;` and a parent div that have `position: fixed ; height: 100vh;`. The child element doesn't go to the bottom, why? Below you have the fullcode. With the inspector, I see the `.secondary` shape on the top, instead to be on the bottom.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fullpagenav active_nav">
  <div id="secondary" class="secondary toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fullpagenav {

    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;

}

.secondary.toggled-on {

    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;

}
```

[image: menu-on-the-top]

Comment: Why not using `position: absolute;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: relative` positions an element relative to *where it would normally be placed*.

That is `bottom: 0` says don't offset the element from where it would normally be placed.

What you're looking for is `position: absolute`

See the description of different position values here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position

In particular, it says this about `relative` (emphasis mine):

> This keyword lays out all elements *as though the element were not positioned, and then adjusts the element's position*, without changing layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have been had it not been positioned).

Answer (score 0):

There can be two solutions by using CSS properties

(i) `vertical-align: bottom;`

(ii) add `position : relative` to parent and `position : absolute` to child

Answer (score 0):

`Bottom` on relatively positioned elements means how far you want to move its bottom from the automatic position. In your case, 0, which makes it stay where it wants.
You need either `position: absolute` or a flexbox:

```
.fullpagenav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: colum;
}

.secondary.toggled-on{
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not how `position: relative` works. It doesn't position elements relative to parent which you are trying to do here when you set `bottom: 0`, and you want that element to be at bottom of parent. That is what `position: absolute` is for but it will take that element out of normal elements flow. So other option is to use `display: flex` on parent element and `align-self: flex-end` on child element.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}
.fullpagenav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
}

.secondary.toggled-on {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullpagenav active_nav">
  <div id="secondary" class="secondary toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
   Div
  </div>
</div>
```